# How to fix java.io.NotSerializable exception when pushing each stage data from jenkins pipeline to influx db?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, influxdb, jenkins-groovy

I’m trying to push stage data from Jenkins pipeline to influx db and I get issue as below

Issue: In jenkin builds console output, after each stage, I see : java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection

Jenkins pipeline 2.150.2
InfluxDB 1.6.2

Any suggestions would be helpful. I'm new to this topic.

Note: I have commented @NonCPS annotation. If I uncomment then it sends only first stage data and exits and fails to iterate for loop which has 20 stages data.

```
//Maps for Field type columns
myDataField1 = [:]
myDataField2 = [:]
myDataField3 = [:]

//Maps for Custom Field measurements
myCustomDataFields1 = [:]
myCustomDataFields2 = [:]
myCustomDataFields3 = [:]

//Maps for Tag type columns
 myDataTag1 = [:]
 myDataTag2 = [:]
 myDataTag3 = [:]

//Maps for Custom Tag measurements
myCustomDataTags1 = [:]
myCustomDataTags2 = [:]
myCustomDataTags3 = [:]

//@NonCPS
def pushStageData() {

def url_string = "${JENKINS_URL}job/ENO_ENG_TP/job/R421/13/wfapi/describe"
def get = new URL(url_string).openConnection();

get.addRequestProperty ("User-Agent","Mozilla/4.0");
get.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic dZXZvceDIwMTk=");

//fetching the contents of the endpoint URL
def jsonText = get.getInputStream().getText();
//converting the text into JSON object using 
JsonSlurperClassic 
def jsonObject = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(jsonText)

// Extracting the details of all the stages present in that particular build number
for (int i=0; i<jsonObject.stages.size()-1; i++){ //size-1 to ignore the post stage
//populating the field type columns of InfluxDB measurements and pushing them to the map called myDataField1
def size = jsonObject.stages.size()-1
myDataField1['result'] = jsonObject.stages[i].status
myDataField1['duration'] = 
jsonObject.stages[i].durationMillis
myDataField1['stage_name'] = jsonObject.stages[i].name

//populating the tag type columns of InfluxDB 
measurements and pushing them to the map called 
myDataTag1
myDataTag1['result_tag'] = jsonObject.stages[i].status
myDataTag1['stage_name_tag'] = jsonObject.stages[i].name

//assigning field type columns to the measurement called CustomData
myCustomDataFields1['CustomData'] = myDataField1
//assigning tag type columns to the measurement called CustomData
myCustomDataTags1['CustomData'] = myDataTag1

//Push the data into influx instance
try
{ step([$class: 'InfluxDbPublisher', target: 'jenkins_data', customPrefix: null, customDataMapTags: myCustomDataTags1]) }

catch (err)
{ println ("pushStagData exception: " + err) }
}
}
```

Expected: I want to push each stages of jenkins pipeline data to influx db.

Comment: You have to use NonCPS. So, please provide the failure reason when using NonCPS.

Comment: @daggett Thank you. When I use NonCPS it iterates for loop just one time(or first stages data) out of 20 stages and exits with status 'push data to influxdb is complete' with no exceptions.

Comment: Could you share what you have inside try-catch? Will it run if you replace it with println...?

Comment: @daggett Thank you. If I replace with println in try it prints the output.

Otherwise it prints below output with influxdb 
InfluxDB Plugin] Collecting data for publication in InfluxDB...
[InfluxDB Plugin] Custom data map found. Writing to InfluxDB...
[InfluxDB Plugin] Publishing data to: [url=http://walvw:8086/, description=Jenkins_Data, username=, password=*****, database=KPI]
[InfluxDB Plugin] Completed
End of pipeline...
SUCCESS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use jenkins' standard methods instead of creating objects manually. You can use [httpRequest](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/#-httprequest-%20perform%20an%20http%20request%20and%20return%20a%20response%20object) instead of URL. This should fix exception you are getting. You can also use [readJson](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) instead of JsonSlurperClassic (latter is optional since classic slurper is actually serializable).

Comment: Thank you.
I tried with httpRequest and I see issue as below

Error when executing always post condition:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: hudson.AbortException: Fail: the returned code 403 is not in the accepted range: [[100399]]
at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:198)

My request is as below
def response = httpRequest
http://banvmlineno08:8080/jenkins/job/ENO_ENG_TP/job/R421/13/wfapi/describe'
println("Status: "+response.status) 
println("Content: "+response.content)

I also installed httpRequest plugin. Any sugeestions?

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked. I made a small change in httpRequest being sent and readJSON
def get = httpRequest acceptType: "APPLICATION_JSON", 
   contentType: "APPLICATION_JSON",
   customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: "token"]],
   url: url_string,
   outputFile: 'dir/test2.json',
   validResponseCodes: '200:404'

Answer (score 1):

you just need to explicitly set `get` to null to make sure there's none non serializable object being instantiated.

```
def jsonText = get.getInputStream().getText();
get = null;
```